# Import CSV file into SQL Server 2012 as SQL function

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, asp-classic

So I am basing my code on the Import to mapped columns question asked by another user.

Here is the code...

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Name nvarchar(max))

 BULK INSERT @TempTable 
 FROM ‘C:\YourFilePath\file.csv’
 WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ‘,’,
 ROWTERMINATOR = ‘\n’
)

INSERT INTO TABLE ([Name], [TypeId])
Select Name,'99E05902-1F68-4B1A-BC66-A143BFF19E37' from @TempTable
```

Do I put this code into a stored procedure or a function to run it from my ASP script?

Comment: A link to the question you have in mind would help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your TypeID a constant at the last line?
2. You can do either SP or TableFunction. But since TableFunction is depandant on the version of SQL Server you have, it might make sense to use SP.